# Is there any shortcut to format the result of a remote query with dblink in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dblink

I am doing a remote query with dblink like this:

```
FROM dblink(
 'port=port
 host=host
 user=user
 password=password
 dbname=dbname',
 'SELECT * FROM roles') 
AS (id integer, created date, modified date, active boolean, role text)
```

Is there a shorter way to specify the column definition instead of typing each column name and type?

Since if there are many columns in the target table, it will be annoying to specify all of them.

Comment: No, there is no alternative when using dblink. But what about using a foreign table instead?

Comment: The solution is [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html).